# How to understand that spring boot application is ready to work?

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

I have several microservices on spring. One of them is config server. I try to start services altogether with docker-compose. But there is problem. Microservices try to get configs from config server before it had been initialized. I want to write script for microservice's startup preventing false start. I have to now how i can determinate moment when my config server is ready. Port listening isn't working. Docker hides info about his networking. I believe there is better way than standard output parsing.

Does somebody know how i can determine time of spring boot application starting?

Comment: What method did you use for port listening?

Comment: If you use actuator you could check the /health endpoint

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does somebody know how i can determine time of spring boot application starting?

Your application must be ready when it returns code `200` from `/health` endpoint with a payload like that

```
{
  "status": "UP"
}
```

It means that your application have no issues and is ready to work, anyway this endpoint is normally used by a monitor application to know about your application health that way it can maintain the cluster, this endpoint is not commonly used by others apps, this monitor commonly

- Uses that endpoint to know when your application is ready to receive world requests, that way it can register your application to a public address for example
- Try to restart that application expecting it can solve it's problem when `/health` returns **DOWN** status

Take a look at [docker healthcheck](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck), it uses the same concept as spring

To have that endpoint available you will need to add spring actuator dependency, here is a gradle sample

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: '1.5.10.RELEASE'
```

> Microservices try to get configs from config server before it had been initialized ....

Here some important points to let clear

- Docker compose don't grants startup order unless you are using [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) clause, anyway docker will never wait to first container completely start up (event using healthcheck) to then start the second container
- If your microservice **A** depends microservice **B** then **A** must be prepared to deal with **B** failure and unavailability, it's a microservice premise, because it will just happens, someday or even worse, in a unexpected moment when it is not supposed to. What about **config-server** restarts in some moment? What will happen with the dependent apps?

So my advise is to you let your application just fail when it tries to get information from **config server** app, if it fails you can do some things:

- Do some kind of retry [using spring-retry](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/retry.html) for example
- If you can deal with some temporary **config server** unavailability then my suggestion is to [add a custom check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44849568/how-to-add-a-custom-health-check-in-spring-boot-health) in your `/health` exposing this information to some monitor microservice
- If your app can't work without **config server**  then just call `System.exit(-1)` and let [docker-compose restart your application](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart) again and again until **config server** answer something helpfull

Here some compact example simulating your case and solving that using docker

- config server
- app-1

**config-server** will ever take longer than **app-1** to get ready, then **app-1** will stay **unhealthy** until **config-server** responds correctly

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  mg-config-server:
    image: nginx:1.10
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "bash", "-c", "sleep 15; exit 0"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 17s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 10s
    networks:
      - my-net
    command: bash -c "echo starting; sleep 20; nginx -g 'daemon off;'"

  mg-app-1:
    image: alpine:3.7
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "http://mg-config-server"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 1s
    command: sh -c 'echo starting; apk add --update curl; tail -f /dev/null'
    restart: always
    networks: 
      - my-net
    dns:
    - 8.8.8.8

networks:
  my-net:
    driver: overlay
```

Then just start it

```
docker-compose up
docker ps | grep "mg"
```

Anyway it makes more sense to use docker swarm in that case, because it will check healthcheck endpoints and restart the containers if it's not healthy

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr <your-machine-ip>
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml my-stack && docker ps | grep "my-stack"
```

Docker version: `18.02.0-ce`

Sorry for the too long answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If your issue is specific to Config server,
You can also implement spring retry mechanism

```
spring:
   application:
      name: test-service
   cloud:
      config:
         enabled: true
         uri: ${CONFIG_SERVER_URL:http://127.0.0.1:8761} #where the config-service is running
         fail-fast: true #the service will not run if it can't reach the config-service
         name: common,test-service
         retry:
           max-attempts: 10
           max-interval: 5000
```

You need to have spring-retry dependency also

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.retry/spring-retry
compile group: 'org.springframework.retry', name: 'spring-retry', version: '1.2.4.RELEASE'
```