# How to implement custom endpoint in Spring Boot actuator to health

Tags: java, endpoint, spring-boot-actuator, health-monitoring

How would I implement a custom endpoint in SpringBoot to achieve the following:

```
http://localhost:8080/actuator/health/custom
```

where "custom" is the endpoint I want to implement that extends health.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a custom health check in spring boot health?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44849568/how-to-add-a-custom-health-check-in-spring-boot-health)

Answer (score 0):

That url is used to expose the Health checks for the application, if that is your situation, you only need to include the dependencies for the actuator :

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>`

and you can see the status of the app.

If you need something more specific, only configure the dependency as you can see [here .](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators)

Also you can override the behavior of the healthchecks but that dependency have a lot of functionality.

Comment: Hello, this will only inject the actuator dependency that allows me to use the default actuator endpoints, such as: /health, /info, /metrics... I want to know how to extend a custom endpoint; e.g, "/actuator/health/custom"