# Implementing health check rest API using custom health indicator for Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, health-monitoring

I am working on Spring Boot web application running on a port other than **8080**. I need to write a rest API for checking the health of the application as well as the underlying database.

Regarding the same, I have gone through this post: [How to add a custom health check in spring boot health?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44849568/how-to-add-a-custom-health-check-in-spring-boot-health), but did not find any concrete implementation.

Actually I would like to do following:

1. Health check for all the downstream APIs
2. Whether DB is working fine

So could anyone please help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot actuator can automatically create common health checks (also for your database) and a REST API for you.

To get started add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Spring boot will then expose some actuator endpoints under:

```
/actuator
```

The most relevant for you is probably:

```
/actuator/health
```

To add a custom health check to this endpoint, you can follow the guide provided in the answer to your linked post.

For more details, please see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators.