# Spring Boot Health Endpoint

Tags: spring, header, endpoint, health-check

I‘m looking for a way to change the header (add some things to it) of the health check of spring boot. I searched for this topic but I only found questions about custom health functions and so on (e.g. [How to add a custom health check in spring boot health?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44849568/how-to-add-a-custom-health-check-in-spring-boot-health?rq=1)).
That‘s not what I am looking for.

I want to use the standard/default health function (so I don‘t want to change the body of the response („status“:“UP“) nor do I want to implement my own health functionality or customize the default one.
My goal is to change the header of the response in order to achieve two things:

- add some things to the header (e.g. max age)
- reaching cors (e.g. I want to set allow-origin to *, allowed-method to GET and so on), I know there is a way to do it in the management properties but this applied for all endpoints and I only want these tgings to apply for the health endpoint

**Is there any way to use the default health check and just modify the header and the properties like allowed origin or do I have to create a new controller?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm looking to solve a similar problem! Did you find any answer? I need to add a header on the health endpoint response, in certain cases.

Answer (score 1):

Just implement your own service with the methods getting the adequate metrics, and then of course your custom controller refering to it. I don't think you can modify those default endpoints..

Here's an example of this custom service:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.MetricsEndpoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SpringActuator {
    @Autowired
    MetricsEndpoint metrics;
    
    public Double getCPU() {
        return metrics.metric("process.cpu.usage", Arrays.asList()).getMeasurements().get(0).getValue();
    }
    
    public Double getRAM() {
        return metrics.metric("jvm.memory.used", Arrays.asList()).getMeasurements().get(0).getValue();
    }
}
```