# Spring Boot app : adding values to health endpoint response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to add custom functionality to health check endpoint.
Created class according to
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44849568/how-to-add-a-custom-health-check-in-spring-boot-health)  post :

```
@Component
public class CustomHealthCheck extends AbstractHealthIndicator {
    @Override
    protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) throws Exception {
        boolean someValue = true;
        if (someValue) {
            builder.withDetail("MyCustomField", "MyValue");
            builder.up();
        } else {
            builder.down();
        }
    }
}
```

But when accessing to health endpoint via postman or via browser
(/actuator/health)
I got response

```
{
    "status": "UP"
}
```

i.e. custom field was not added to the response
I also see in debugger , that doHealthCheck method of CustomHealthCheck was executed

Here are relevant definitions from application.properties :

```
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=true
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoint.info.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info
```

Is there something missing in the code or definitions ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

By providing a bean implementing `HealthIndicator`, you contribute a *custom* health indicator, rather than overriding some default. The base `/actuator/health` then returns an aggregate over all registered beans, including yours.

Try naming your bean `CustomHealthIndicator` and you should be able to see your detail under `/actuator/health/custom`.