# How to execute all the defaults health indicators with custom health endpoint?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In my application we have standard spring boot actuator health endpoint --> /health.
I have disabled db health check with below configuration in application.yml

management:
health:
db:
enabled: false

I have created new custom health endpoint in that I want to perform deep health check.
It should check the health of current service with db health check and its dependent service health check.
As I have disabled db health in standard actuator how can I perform deep health check with db health check in custom health endpoint.

I have registered the db health indicator programmatically but it get register for health endpoint also.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a custom health check in spring boot health?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44849568/how-to-add-a-custom-health-check-in-spring-boot-health)